# Valid MySQL Delete Query returning non-object

Tags: php, mysql

This one's a mystery to me and no one that I've read up on so far has had this issue, and I'm losing my mind here, so here goes.  I'm trying to run this simple query from php on a mysql database with a user that has all required privileges (usually there is more than one entry in the ID array):

```
$sqlDelete = 'DELETE FROM wsa.customers WHERE `id` IN (18)';
$result = $conn->query($sqlDelete);
```

When I run this code from phpmyadmin and workbench this executes just fine, but not using php on the server (though it does handle updates and inserts without issue).

The $result is not a result object (though it should be) and I see no error or warnings at all...everything is as if nothing went badly though the user is obviously not deleted.

I'd just like to get input on where I should be looking as this is not a syntax issue....I've run out of ideas.

Thanks

UPDATE ON SCHEMA QUESTION:

```
CREATE TABLE `agreements` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `creator_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `term` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `contractDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `creatorid_idx` (`creator_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `userid` FOREIGN KEY (`creator_id`) REFERENCES `master`.`login` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `agreement_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `plan` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `agreementid_idx` (`agreement_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `agr_id` FOREIGN KEY (`agreement_id`) REFERENCES `agreements` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

UPDATE 2: Connnection Details:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'xxx';
$dbpass = 'yyy';
$conn;

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, 'wsa'); 

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
}
```

Comment: question is, why does your ID column contain more than one ID number for each row? you need to show us your DB schema or see what the person below has provided your with as an answer.

Comment: Plus, a non-object error can be associated with something else, such as code you're not showing us and depending on how it's queried and the connection used. The API you're using is unknown but seems to be mysqli so if you're not using proper error checking, visit http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  and apply that to your query. If PDO, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: I've just added the schema for reference, as requested.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Yet, see my second comment which is sometimes the fault or a contributing factor.

Comment: The query I'm running will usually delete more than one row, which is why there will typically be an array if IDs, but in the example I'm showing one for simplicity

Comment: Thanks Fred....I actually tried the $conn->error function but it gave me nothing, which is why I'm confused: no error is being shown and yet the connection is fine because updates and inserts are working.  But the user has delete privs so its not a privs issue I don't think

Comment: Since you have a foreign key make sure that you delete the row with that respective id from agreements first.

Comment: @Mihai: the foreign key is meant to stop deleting agreements when there are customers.  There should be no issue deleting customers while leaving the agreement intact (I'm trying to do the latter).  If it was a key constraint issue the query would have been rejected in workbench and phpmyadmin, but it isn't

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` or PDO`?

Comment: @Darwin I'm using mysqli, and I've never seen an issue like this before.

Comment: [`mysqli::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns `true` or `false` on a non-`SELECT` query.

Comment: @Darwin: my issue is that it should be deleting the user from the db when it isn't.  I'm testing whether it's working or not by `if (!is_object($result))`  Updating the test to `if($conn->query($sqlDelete))` is better I agree, but my underlying problem remains

Comment: It returns `true` on success; that isn't an object. Is it that the record actually isn't being deleted, or that the PHP isn't saying that it was?

Comment: @Darwin that the record is not being deleted

Comment: Show more code,especially the connection

Comment: If you haven't already done so, call `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your code, and put a `print_r($conn->error_list);` right after your `query()`.

Comment: @Mihai Just added them to main question

Comment: @Darwin I've tried the `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and see nothing.  No error is being triggered, yet the user is not deleted....this is why I've posted here

Comment: I'm still learning this too, but I have an idea for your code that might help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks...in the end I was erroneously using `if(!result)` to test whether the query went through on a previous insert query to the one shown and it was causing the whole transaction to fail.  My apologies.  Thanks to @Darwin von Corax for pointing me in the right direction.